# default gateway and tracert

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, gateway

when i do "route print" on my machine, it shows my default gateway as 10.225.150.1

but when i do tracert www.google.com, the first machine it reaches is 10.225.150.2. The route command does not show any entry for 10.225.150.2.

So, why tracert is showing 10.225.150.2?

my maching is on Windows XP.

Comment: Can you send the output of 

ipconfig /all
tracert www.google.com
route print 

J

Answer (score 2):

If your gateway is [Multihomed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming) it might have several IPs assigned to it but traceroute will only show one. The one shown doesn't have to be the one you're using as your default GW. You would find this kind of setup on corporate networks mostly, not so much with home routers.

Answer (score 2):

If the IP of the gateway has recently changed, you may have stale arp cache. Validate that you do not have the 150.2 IP associated with the hardware address of your gateway. Your arp cache can be inspected with:

```
arp -a
```

or cleared with:

```
arp -d *
```

Is the condition you describe in your questions currently causing a problem for you or just a curiosity? If a problem, can you provide specifics for what you're trying to accomplish?